# How to identify and click to the button in selenium webdriver when button does not have id and title, but has hover state?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone tell me how I can identify and click to the button which does not have title?

```
<div class="ui-fileupload-buttonbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-top">
  <span class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left ui-fileupload-choose">
  <span class="ui-button-icon-left ui-icon ui-c ui-icon-plusthick"></span>
  <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Browse</span>
  <input id="j_idt126:attachments:j_idt128_input" name="j_idt126:attachments:j_idt128_input" type="file">
```

I have tried by below code but it is not working

```
By.xpath("//button[@type='button']/span[text()='Browse']"))).click();
```

How can I solve this problem in Selenium WebDriver with Java? Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: please also include the code for the button element.

Comment: I edited my original post.

Comment: still can't see an element with type=button ? did you miss to add the button element or what do you think the button element is?

Comment: This isn't my webpage and doesn't have the button element. I don't know why.

Comment: ok, then it's clear that your xpath is not working -> if there is no button element, then your xpath searching for one will just find nothing! So better describe what exactly you want to do, or even better post the page you are trying to automate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the file upload input, you'll get a system file upload window that you cannot control.

Instead locate the element and sends the absolute path to the file you want to upload:

```
WebElement uploadInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[. = 'Browse']/following-sibling::input[@type='file']"));
uploadInput.sendKeys("/absolute/path/to/a/file");
```

Here we locating the input relying on the previous sibling's `Browse` text.